# Visual Studio Default Interface?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to switch Visual Studio 2012 interface from .NET to C++ - I have selected .NET during first run, and now I dont know how to change it to C++.

At the moment it shows only .NET projects when I make "New Projects", and there seems to be no way to create anything else than that, however I have installed full version with other gadgets.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with 2010 if you're talking about 2012? Which edition are you working in?

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps like this:-

1) Tools -> Import and Export Settings...

2) Select "Reset all settings" and click Next

3) Choose "Yes" if you want to keep your existing settings

4) Click Next

5) Select the profile of your choice and click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think that the environment settings actually *hid* any particular project types, but the way to re-access the "which settings do you want to use?" dialog is under Tools -> Import and Export Settings.

One of the options is Reset all Settings, which then lets you select which defaults you wish to use.